# how to get rid of extra characters added to curl command in function call in bash

Tags: bash, curl

I have a bash function that calls a curl command to perform some jenkins operation(remove a shelved projects)

```
function get_data {
        local user="${1}"               # user
        local api_token="${2}"          # token
        local http_method="${3}"        # POST
        local rest_call_url="${4}"      
        local other_curl_opt="${5}"     # -H "Content-Type:application/json" -H "X-Api:asdhds890asd"

         # encode space characters
         rest_call_url=$(echo "$rest_call_url" | sed 's/ /%20/g')

         # gets data
         data=$(curl -u ${user}:${api_token} -k -s ${other_curl_opt} -X $http_method "${rest_call_url}")
         return_status=$?

        if [[ "${data}" = *"HTTP Status 404"* ]] || [[ "${data}" = *"HTTP ERROR 404"* ]] || [[ "${data}" = *"Bad parameter"* ]] || [ $return_status -ne 0 ]
        then
                print_log ${job_name} ERROR "Curl command failed"
        else
                print_log ${job_name} INFO "Curl command successful"
        fi
}
```

this function is called in one more function after passing the required parameters

this is the function call

```
jenkins_operation_url=https://${jenkins_instance}/shelvedProjects/manageShelvedProject/
                                    opts="--data \"projects=${job_name}\" --data \"delete=\""
                                    get_data "${jenkins_user}" "${api_token}" "POST" "${jenkins_operation_url}" "${opts}"
```

Now the issue is when this function is called there are some extra characters that get added to the curl call

sample data is

```
curl -u user:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx -k -s --data '"projects=xxxxa"' --data '"delete="' -X POST https://xxxxxxxx/shelvedProjects/manageShelvedProject/
+ data='Bad parameter. Should be '\''unshelve'\'' or '\''delete'\'' only.'
```

i am not sure from where these extra characters(the single quotes) are getting added

```
--data '"projects=xxxxa"' --data '"delete="'
```

Can someone please help in correcting my code

Answer (score 0):

when you give a value to a variable, you should use always quotes except for numbers like this:

```
jenkins_operation_url="https://${jenkins_instance}/shelvedProjects/manageShelvedProject/"
```